# Error loading GraphSON data into a DSE graph with custom vertex ids

Tags: tinkerpop, datastax-enterprise-graph, graphson

I have created a schema with a custom vertex id like:

`schema.vertexLabel('foo').partitionKey('_id').ifNotExists().create()`

I then populated a graph with data. Now I'd like to transfer that data to another graph via GraphSON. The new graph instance has the same schema.

To do this I first exported the data from the populated graph:

`graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph('/integration-data/flex-test-data.json')`

However, when I try to import the data into the empty graph instance with:

`graph.io(graphson()).readGraph('/integration-data/flex-test-data.json')`

I get an error "Vertices with custom IDs must have their IDs specified on creation." This worked before I made the switch to custom ids. I have confirmed that the ids are present in the exported file.

Is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what version of DSE Graph are you running.  There was a defect that was resolved in 5.1.6 for this issue.

DSP-14568

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html#RNdse516__516resIss

Comment: Great that's it. I'm on 5.1.0. I'll remember to check the release notes in the future.